# Map keyboard shortcuts in Google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to remap certain keyboard shortcuts (most notably: 'ctrl-f' to '/' in order to invoke the search) in chrome? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb) a chrome extension you may find useful.

Comment: This appears to be Vim-specific, but good call

Comment: Please provide more explanatory context, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there doesn't appear to be an easy way to do it.

Googling turns up mention of a "[Shortcut manager](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf)" extension, but it appears to be incompatible with the later versions of chrome.

I agree with your frustration - I'm always trying to search with '/'.