# Tabs shrinking in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, browser-tabs

Is there any way to prevent tabs from shrinking when I open many (I mean 20, 30 or even more). Something like in Firefox - it just moves them "behind the scene". It can be some extension or hack.

Comment: I'm a heavy user of tabs but I know that the best way to use them is in combination with windows. For example on this user I have 53 tabs open in 9 windows about 5.5 tabs per window or on my other user I have 254 tabs in like 30 windows about 8.4 tab per window. So I don't have a problem with chrome's behavior here. (although I did have _tree style tabs_ in the copy of firefox I sometimes use)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may assist you, I am still hunting for an exact clone of the firefox and IE style of dealing with tabs (multiple pages of same sized tabs)

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/amigcgbheognjmfkaieeeadojiibgbdp

Comment: I am using now [VerticalTabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imimolldggofidcmfdkcffpjcgaggoaf), but I was looking for the "anti shrinking thing".

Answer (score 0):

I think these extensions will help you: Recent Tabs (for MRU switching with Ctrl+Q), TooManyTabs, Tab Menu, TabsOutliner, SingleFile, VerticalTabs

And thanks to Shrikant Sharat Kandula for explaining how to set shortcut keys for extensions in Chrome!: 
<<
And to those wanting a hotkey, go to your extensions page in chrome and scroll to the bottom. If you see a link at the bottom right saying 'Configure Commands', that's what you need. I use `Ctrl+i` for this hotkey, since it is easy to hit for touch typists like me :).

> >

There's also another extension that allows you to map shortcuts and do VI/VIM style searching (i.e. use / instead of Ctrl-F): 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb/reviews
-- Thanks to A Clockwork Orange for this tip from [Map keyboard shortcuts in Google chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/261752/map-keyboard-shortcuts-in-google-chrome) )

I think it's not good proper procedure to ask here, but I've done a lot of searching and haven't found an answer.  Do you know of a keyboard shortcut to open a new tab in Chrome adjacent to the current one? Ctrl+T opens a new tab all the way to the right. Grrr.

This, along with lack of tab switching in MRU order, are the main reasons I use IE, Opera and Firefox more than Chrome.  IE and Opera can also save a webpage as a single file.

Comment: Please don't ask questions in an answer. also please be more specific: How do these extensions solve the problem of shrinking tabs?